# Idiomatic and efficient way to get a vector filter and its complement

Tags: vector, filter, rust

Suppose I have a vector, a filter over it, and I want to deconstruct it into two vectors: A filtered vector, and its complement. I see two ways to do this. The first is with a for loop:

```rust
let vct: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12];
let filter = |x| x % 3 == 0;

let mut filtered: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
let mut complement: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
for v in vct {
    if filter(v) {
        filtered.push(v);
    } else {
        complement.push(v);
    }
}

println!("{:?}", filtered);   //[3, 9, 12]
println!("{:?}", complement); //[1, 4, 7, 10]
```

This seems efficient, but unnecessarily verbose (and adds unnecessary mutability to the vectors). The other one is a naive way with iterators:

```rust
let vct: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12];
let filter = |x:&&u32| *x % 3 == 0;

let filtered: Vec<u32> = vct.iter().filter(filter).cloned().collect();
let complement: Vec<u32> = vct.into_iter().filter(|x| !filter(&x)).collect();

println!("{:?}", filtered);   //[3, 9, 12]
println!("{:?}", complement); //[1, 4, 7, 10]
```

Which has a clearer intent and is less verbose (save the `filter` definition/usage, which is a bit uglier), but iterates *twice* over the array, which seems unnecessary.

Both of these solutions seem sub-optimal.

Is there an idiomatic *and* efficient way (without re-iteration) to split a vector into a filter and its complement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation you are attempting to do is called *partitioning*. You can use [Iterator.partition()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition):

```rust
let vct: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12];
let filter: fn(u32) -> bool = |x| x % 3 == 0;

let (filtered, complement): (Vec<u32>, Vec<u32>) = vct.iter().partition(|x| filter(**x));

assert_eq!(&[3, 9, 12], filtered.as_slice());
assert_eq!(&[1, 4, 7, 10], complement.as_slice());
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b866176c714769d9b75a67eb37ad0140)